# Center type accurately within my headline div

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm currently having some issues with trying to find a way to center this h2 within a div class called headline-services.

I have a text-align:center; applied to my h2 which is (only) allowing the text to center within the (text) and it's not centering the text within the div box. What I would like to achieve is to have the white text in the center of the green box.

// Note //

The the text may look centered but it's not really accurate... 
I've applied a padding-top to the h2 class which is allowing it up move down towards the center of the box but as I mentioned before this not an accurate way to go about centering this h2 within a div.

http://kapena.github.io/pp_web/

```
.plumbing-repairs{
font-family: Avenir;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
font-size: 50pt;
color: white;
margin: 0px;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 55px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following lines of CSS to the element you want to center vertically;

```
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

[Reference](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/)

Also, for clarity, `text-align:center;` only applies horizontal centering.

Comment: Worth reading the reference, contains information about half pixels that may be important :)

Comment: Thank you for you're help! It works and I had a read through the article. Great read I did some research into this technique and it seems to be quite compatible. However, I am now facing a new issue...Just bellow the main image on the home page I have a light blue box and inside it says -- "You're Satisfaction, Our Strongest Point" I tried to apply the technique to this text but it breaks my entire home page layout and boxes go flying...I tinkered with it for a while today but just could not find a way to make it work. I think it's a parenting issue..any ideas? Using the padding method atm..

Comment: What exactly is broken about it? It is vertically centered.

Comment: I managed to figure out how to fix it before you replied! Thax for getting back to me tho! :)